# Is the Mystery Train expansion for Ticket to Ride available in sizes matching the 1910 expansion?

Tags: ticket-to-ride

I have a set of Mystery Train expansion cards that I printed and laminated myself (they're not the most pleasant to play with, but they work). Since I got the 1910 expansion for Ticket to Ride, I haven't really used the Mystery Train expansion because the cards' sizes don't match. The destination tickets from Mystery Train are included, but I'm looking for the character cards (*Engineer*, *Tycoon*, *Inspector*, *Station Agent*, and the blank character card).

Is there a professionally-printed version or a printable PDF for the full-size cards?

Comment: I thought the 1910 expansion included the Mystery Train expansion?

Comment: @Lance, my copy of 1910 included it.  Perhaps the OP has an older printing?

Comment: @Lance @Kristo I have the Mystery Train _destination tickets_ but not the character cards (like _Engineer_); my copy of the 1910 expansion is the version that came in a tin, not in a box.

Comment: Yeah, the destination tickets is all that came in my tin.

Comment: @Lance, thanks! I'll clarify that in the question, then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [this](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/thread/523268/mystery-train-officially-discontinued) in my digging through the web (posted Friday, May 7, 2010 4:48 pm):

> The other day I was following some links and clicked on the URL for the Mystery Train expansion: http://www.daysofwonder.com/tickettoride/en/mystery/
>
> I noticed that the page for this was no longer valid (though it had been live just a few months ago)
>
> Curious about this, I wrote Customer Support at Days of Wonder, and they replied:
>
> > Thank you for your request.
> >
> > Support for this expansion has been discontinued.
> >
> > Best Regards,
> >
> > Yann Corno - Customer Service -  Days of Wonder - Come out and play!
>
> Now, luckily, I had archived the old Mystery Train pages before they disappeared. My mirror of that site can be found here: http://www.tannerworld.com/mysterytrain/

There are statements on two other pages on BoardGameGeek ([1](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/thread/221791/with-1910) and [2](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/137055/mystery-train-expansion)) that say there's no such thing available.

One workaround would be to resize the cards (and fix the images so they look okay at the new scale), but distributing the modified PDF could be copyright infringement.